# Do an update without knowing the ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this request:

```
UPDATE PEOPLE SET ID_STATE = 5 WHERE ID_STATE IN (3,4);
```

I would make the same request but if I do not know the `ID_STATE` but just the `labelStatePeople`

```
SELECT ID_STATE FROM STATE_PEOPLE WHERE labelStatePeople = 'blue';
```

***EXAMPLE:***

```
$1 = SELECT ID_STATE FROM STATE_PEOPLE WHERE labelStatePeople = 'blue';
$2 = SELECT ID_STATE FROM STATE_PEOPLE WHERE labelStatePeople = 'yellow';
$3 = SELECT ID_STATE FROM STATE_PEOPLE WHERE labelStatePeople = 'red';
```

***final request:*** `UPDATE PEOPLE SET ID_STATE = $1 WHERE ID_STATE IN ($2,$3);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply have a sub-query that returns those strange people's ID_STATE values:

```
UPDATE PEOPLE
  SET ID_STATE = 5
WHERE ID_STATE IN (SELECT ID_STATE FROM STATE_PEOPLE
                   WHERE labelStatePeople = 'strange'
                    and ID_STATE IS NOT NULL)
```

(The sub-query's `ID_STATE IS NOT NULL` part can be removed if that column is `NOT NULL`.)

Comment: I updated my post to a better understanding of my problem

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this `IS NOT NULL` needed for performance reasons? (Assuming the column can be NULL)

Comment: @kamilk, no, the reason is that if the sub-qeury returns a NULL, the WHERE clause will be false, and no rows at all will be updated - even if the sub-qeury also returns valid ID_STATE values. (Very common mistake.)

Comment: how can include two `SELECT` query in `WHERE ID_STATE IN ($2,$3);`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UPDATE PEOPLE
SET ID_STATE = 5
WHERE ID_STATE 
IN (SELECT ID_STATE FROM STATE_PEOPLE
WHERE labelStatePeople 
IN ('blue','yellow','red') 
AND ID_STATE IS NOT NULL );
```